# How to add google search suggestion for browser app in android?

Tags: android, browser, google-search

I am working on a browser application, I need to add google search suggestion feature. If the user entered a character in **edittext** it should display related keywords to search, like amazon India, amazon prime video.

Comment: search TextWatcher.It should give you a hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to make server call to google search engine we get callback response in xml format then we have to parse it and display it on listview.

here is the url-http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=a

a stand for keyword that need suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutocompleteTextView and change string array with your own service to get suggested keywords

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Get the string array
        val keywords = resources.getStringArray(R.array.keywords_array)
        // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, keywords)
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
}
```